# How can I record audio from another application into Adobe Audition 5.5 on a mac?

Tags: audio-recording

I have a Firewire 410 audio interface and Macbook Pro running Snow Leopard & Adobe Audition 5.5. I would like to record the audio output from another application e.g. a stream in a browser into a stereo track in Adobe Audition. Is this possible?

I have Audio Hardware Inputs set to FireWire410 Multichannel in Audition's preferences but am not sure how to route the audio into Audition.

Answer (score 3):

It's been  a while since i last worked on a mac but i remember having the same problem and "Soundflower" did the job.

http://code.google.com/p/soundflower/

Another possibility(if you are trying to send audio from one DAW to another)is the VST/AU plugin "Wormhole".

http://code.google.com/p/wormhole2/